# Perform Arithmetic operation in object initializer list c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

Can I dynamically update the list in the below way, like total amount = firstamount + secondamount?. If not, what is the most ideal method to do this?

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test 
    { 
        Name ="ABC",
        FirstAmount = 10,
        SecondAmount = 20,
        TotalAmount = FirstAmount + SecondAmount                                                                                                
    }
};    

public class Test
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public decimal FirstAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal SecondAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your total will always be the sum of the other two, you can do this:

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test { Name ="ABC",FirstAmount =10,SecondAmount =20}
};

public class Test
{
    public String Name {set;get;}

    public decimal FirstAmount {set;get;}

    public decimal SecondAmount {set;get;}

    public decimal TotalAmount { get { return FirstAmount + SecondAmount; } }
}
```

Comment: How do i get the "total amount value" into the list say if i wanted to bind the list to a grid.How do i access the object in the class ?

Comment: Just use the `TotalAmount` property. Do you want that field to be editable?

Comment: Say i have a collection of list objects like  List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test { Name ="ABC",FirstAmount =10,SecondAmount =20}  new Test { Name ="XYZ",FirstAmount =20,SecondAmount =30}
};  In this case how do i call the property as that would be bound to a grid

Comment: Just call it. It's there. Have you tried to call it?

Answer (score 4):

Can you change your object so it is a getter on `TotalAmount`... something like

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test { Name ="ABC",FirstAmount =10,SecondAmount =20}
};

public class Test
{
    public String Name {set;get;}

    public decimal FirstAmount {set;get;}

    public decimal SecondAmount {set;get;}

    public decimal TotalAmount {get {return FirstAmount + SecondAmount;}}
}
```

Comment: @Magus Done - I copied the code from the OP's posting and re-pasted it vanilla :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access the properties of the object being initialized, except to set them.

In this case, the simplest workaround is to use intermediate variables:

```
int firstAmount = 10;
int secondAmount = 20;

List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test { Name ="ABC",FirstAmount = firstAmount,SecondAmount = secondAmount ,TotalAmount = firstAmount + secondAmount}
};
```

Comment: I know about this workaround but i was curious if we can do in the above mentioned way

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a constructor:

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test> 
{
    new Test(
        name: "ABC",
        firstAmount: 10,
        secondAmount: 20                                                                                            
    )
};    

public class Test
{
    public Test(string name, decimal firstAmount, decimal secondAmount)
    {
        Name = name;
        FirstAmount = firstAmount;
        SecondAmount = secondAmount;
        TotalAmount = firstAmount + secondAmount;
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public decimal FirstAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal SecondAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Whit this approach, your `TotalAmount` property remains editable.

Comment: How can i return the "TotalAmount" value into the list to bind it to a grid ?

Comment: Can you post the code you use for biding the grid that doesn't work? I'm not understanding your question